# Is this a correct way to use the digamma to analyze whether a ratio of gamma functions is increasing?

Tags: derivatives, inequality, prime-numbers, gamma-function, digamma-function

Let:

- $\pi(x)$ be the [prime counting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function)
- $\psi(x)$ be the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function)

Given that $\pi(x) < \dfrac{1.25506n}{\ln n}$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#Inequalities)), let:

$$f(n) = \frac{\Gamma\left(2n + 1 - \frac{1.25506n}{\ln n} \right)}{[\Gamma(n+1)]^2}$$

I am trying to determine if $f(n)$ is increasing or decreasing for $n \ge 631$

While it has been suggested that [Stirling's Approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) is the way to go, I decided to see what happens by using the Digamma Function.

Here are my assumptions.  Please let me know if any of these assumptions are wrong or any of steps are wrong.

(1)  $f(n)$ is increasing if and only if $\ln f(n)$ is increasing where:

$$\ln f(n) = \ln\Gamma\left(2n + 1 - \frac{1.25506n}{\ln n}\right) - 2\ln\Gamma(n+1)$$

(2) $\psi(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\left(\ln \Gamma(x)\right)$ so that after applying the [Chain Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule):

$$\frac{d}{dn}(\ln f(n)) = \psi\left(2n + 1 - \frac{1.25506n}{\ln n} \right)\left(2 - \frac{1.25506}{\ln(x)} + \frac{1.25006}{(\ln x)^2}\right) - 2\psi(n+1)$$

(3) The following Series equation (from Inequalities [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Series_formula)), applies:

$$\psi(z+1) = -\gamma + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{z}{n(n+z)}\right),\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, z \ne -1, -2, -3, \dots$$

Here's my attempt to resolve the question.   Unfortunately, I am ending up with a counterintuitive conclusion that $\frac{d}{dn}(\ln f(n)) < 0$

(1)  $\frac{d}{dn}(\ln f(n))$ can be restated to:

$$\frac{d}{dn}(\ln f(n)) = \psi\left(2n + 1 - \frac{1.25506n}{\ln n} \right)\left(2 - \frac{1.25506}{\ln(x)} + \frac{1.25006}{(\ln x)^2}\right) - 2\psi(n+1) =  \left(2 - \frac{1.25506}{\ln(x)} + \frac{1.25006}{(\ln x)^2}\right)\left[-\gamma + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{2n - \frac{1.25506n}{\ln n}}{k\left(k+2n - \frac{1.25506n}{\ln n}\right)}\right)\right] - 2\left[-\gamma + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{n}{k(k+n)}\right)\right]$$

(2)  For $x \ge 631$:

$$2 - \frac{1.25506}{\ln(x)} + \frac{1.25006}{(\ln x)^2} > 1.8$$

So that:

$$\frac{d}{dn}(\ln f(n))  < -1.9\gamma + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{3.8n - \frac{2.384614n}{\ln n}}{k\left(k+2n - \frac{1.25506n}{\ln n}\right)}\right) +2\gamma - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{2n}{k(k+n)}\right)$$

(3) The conclusion is shown if for $k \ge 1$,

$$\left(\frac{3.8n - \frac{2.384614n}{\ln n}}{k\left(k+2n - \frac{1.25506n}{\ln n}\right)}\right) < \frac{2n}{k(k+n)}$$

(4) Here is the argument:

$$ 0.9k + \frac{0.062753n}{\ln n} < 0.1n + \left(\frac{1.192307k}{\ln n}\right)$$

$$ 1.9k + 1.9n + \frac{0.062753n}{\ln n} < k + 2n + \left(\frac{1.192307k}{\ln n}\right)$$

$$\left(1.9k - \frac{1.192307k}{\ln n}\right)+ \left(1.9n - \frac{1.192307n}{\ln n}\right) < \left(k+2n - \frac{1.25506n}{\ln n}\right)$$

$$\left(1.9 - \frac{1.192307}{\ln n}\right)(k+n) < \left(k+2n - \frac{1.25506n}{\ln n}\right)$$

$$\left(3.8 - \frac{2.384614}{\ln n}\right)(k+n) < (2)\left(k+2n - \frac{1.25506n}{\ln n}\right)$$

$$\left(3.8n - \frac{2.384614n}{\ln n}\right)[k(k+n)] < (2n)\left[k\left(k+2n - \frac{1.25506n}{\ln n}\right)\right]$$

---

**Edit:**

I change the point I am checking to $631$ which reflects the point where Excel is suggesting that the result is greater than $1$.

See my Bounty explanation for details.

**Edit 2:**

Made fix suggested by Integrand to apply the [Chain Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule)

Comment: Just a comment: I think your lower bound of $107$ might be too ambitious. Numerical results suggest $n=160$ is more accurate. Will look at the rest of it later.

Comment: A more substantive error: in (2), the derivative is
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \ln(f(x)) =  \psi\left(2x+1-\frac{1.25506 x}{\log(x)}\right)\color{red}{\cdot \left(2+\frac{1.25506}{\log ^2(x)}-\frac{1.25506}{\log (x)}\right)}-2 \psi(x+1);
$$this follows from the Chain Rule. I'll keep looking at it though.

Comment: Thanks!  I knew there was at least one major problem.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, the derivative in (2) is
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \ln(f(x)) =  \psi\left(2x+1-\frac{1.25506 x}{\log(x)}\right)\color{red}{\cdot \left(2+\frac{1.25506}{\log ^2(x)}-\frac{1.25506}{\log (x)}\right)}-2 \psi(x+1);
$$this follows from the Chain Rule. Let $k$ be an arbitrary constant and let $c=1.25506$ be the constant you mentioned. For brevity, I'll denote $g_k(x)=2x+1-\frac{k x}{\ln x}$ and $f_k(x)=\Gamma(g_k(x))/\Gamma(x+1)^2$.

**A partial resolution: $f_c(x)$ is eventually increasing.**

Start with $\ln(f_k(x))$:
$$
\ln(f_k(x)) = \ln\left(\Gamma\big(g_k(x)\big)\right)-2\ln(\Gamma(x+1))
$$Since everything is positive, we can use Binet's log-gamma formula:
$$
\ln(\Gamma(z))=-z+\left(z-\frac{1}{2}\right) \log (z)+\frac{1}{2} \log (2 \pi )+2 \int_0^{\infty } \frac{\arctan\left(\frac{t}{z}\right)}{\exp (2 \pi 
   t)-1} \, dt
$$Of note: the integral is decreasing as $z$ increases, has a very small value, and approaches $0$ in the limit as $z\to\infty$. So we have
$$
\ln(f_k(x)) = 1-\frac{1}{2} \log (2
   \pi )+2 \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\arctan(t/g_k(x))-\arctan(t/(x+1))}{e^{2\pi t}-1}\,dt
$$
$$\underbrace{-2 x \log (x+1)+\frac{k x(1- \log \left(g_k(x))\right)}{\log
   (x)}+2 x \log \left(g_k(x)\right)-\log
   (x+1)+\frac{1}{2} \log \left(g_k(x)\right)}_{F_k(x)}
$$Here's the good part: if we disregard the integral (to be justified momentarily), then a *messy but routine* calculation gives:
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{d}{dx}F_k(x)\right) = -k +\log(4)
$$In particular, when $k=c$, the value is approximately $0.131234>0$. So, assuming we can explain away that pesky integral, then $f_c(x)$ is eventually increasing. Note that for $x>100$, say, we have $1<x+1<g_1(x)$. Further, $g_1(x)$ and $x+1$ are continuous, positive, and increasing without bound. Then for some $\xi=\xi(x)>x$, we have
$$
2 \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\arctan(t/g_1(x))-\arctan(t/(x+1))}{e^{2\pi t}-1}\,dt
$$
$$
=-2 \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\arctan(t/\xi)}{e^{2\pi t}-1}\,dt
$$This integral is *increasing* in $x$ and approaches $0$ as $x\to\infty$. At this point, we have shown that $f_c(x)$ is eventually increasing.

Some things I 'know' are obvious but cannot prove right now:

- $f_c(x)$ has a minimum at $x\approx 159$.
- For $0<k<\log(4)$, $f_k(x)$ is convex (this would immediately give what you want). I think this has something to do with the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \psi(2x)-2\psi(x)=\log(2)$.

Answer (score 2):

*Based on Stirlin approximation and Taylor series.*

Considering the function
$$f(x)=\log \left(\frac{\Gamma \left(2x+1-\frac{a}{\log (x)}\right)}{\Gamma
   (x+1)^2}\right)\qquad \text{where} \qquad a=1.25506$$
Using Stirling approximation followed by Taylor expansions up to $O(\frac 1x)$, we have
$$f(x)=\frac{x \left(-a \log (x)-(a-2 \log (x)) \log \left(2-\frac{a}{\log
   (x)}\right)+a\right)}{\log (x)}+$$ $$\left(\log \left(2-\frac{a}{\log
   (x)}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \log \left(-\frac{\log (x)}{2 \pi x(  a -2  \log
   (x))}\right)\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$ This function cancels at $x=630.914$ (the exact solution being $x=630.922$) goes through a minimum value of $-7.05053$ for $x=159.320$ (the exact solution being $-7.05128$ at $x=159.285$).

Much more tedious calculations shows that the minimum is unique. So $f(x)$ is an increasing function for any $x\geq 160$.